# Why can't I use simple mail() function in PHP to send emails to my Gmail account from my PC?

Tags: php, email

I have an XAMPP installed on my PC, and I wanted to send an email to my Gmail account, however, it's not working. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$to = "yjhjerry621@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "yjhjerry621@qq.com";
$headers = "From: $from";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Here is my setting in php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.qq.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = yjhjerry621@qq.com
```

Here is what I've got from the browser:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]:
>   Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "localhost" port 25, verify your
>   "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in
>   php.ini or use ini_set() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpemail.php on line 7

Comment: mail function returns a bool.  you should examine that to determine if there is a problem on your end or with gmail.

Answer (score 2):

Is your php.ini pointing to a valid SMTP server?  Check for this section in php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

and confirm that valid values are set.  Does your PHP error log contain any useful errors after attempting to run the script?

Comment: Here is setting in my php.ini: **[mail function]
SMTP = smtp.qq.com,
smtp_port = 25**  Are all these enough?

Comment: Depends on whether smtp.qq.com is set up as an SMTP server and is functioning correctly.  Try "telnet smtp.qq.com 25" (should work on Windows or Linux) and verify that you receive a 220 response.  If you don't, that would indicate that the problem is not with your PHP code, but with your SMTP server.

Comment: @RyanMitchell：The mailserver seems working fine(here is info from telnet: `220 esmtp10.qq.com Esmtp QQ Mail Server`). The warning I got from the web browser seems to want a 'localhost'(this doesn't work, I've tried) while I set it to 'smtp.qq.com'(a remote mailserver).

Comment: Hmm - are you sure that the php.ini you're looking at (that lists smtp.qq.com) is the one that's being used?  PHP seems to think otherwise and is looking for localhost.  Try viewing phpinfo.php on your site (or do a php -i from the web server) and it will tell you which php.ini file it's getting its configuration from.  If it's somewhere other than where you're looking, just correct the SMTP ini setting on the correct php.ini.

Comment: @RyanMitchell: Thank you for the reply, I really appreciate it. I am using xampp as my webserver on a windows PC. I did all the setting in the directory: `C:xampp\php\php.ini`, and that's exactly what I was told the directory used when viewing phpinfo.php :(

Comment: Strange - at any rate, unless I'm missing something, it seems clear that SOMETHING is telling PHP that the mailserver is at localhost.  I can't imagine what that would be other than a different php.ini file.  You could use brute force and ini_set the value of SMTP directly before the call to mail() just for troubleshooting purposes - if you run 'php -i' does it also point to 'C:\xampp\php\php.ini'?

Comment: @RyanMitchell: It suddenly occurs to me that I was very wrong in the very beginning! I mean, how could this even possible, one can't just send emails from a random email account(in this case, yjhjerry621@qq.com) that one haven't get himself authenticated!

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP should of installed some applications for you. One of them is the Mercury Mail. In there you can go and configure your SMTP server.

Basically what happens is that when you are trying to send an email using PHP's mail function, in order to do it, it needs to send it using SMTP, so if you have not set the up correctly, the function will not be able to establish a connection and therefore will not be able to send the mail.

Comment: in Mercury mail, you will have to point your SMTP host to the SMTP host of your ISP (the company which gives you your internet connection). If you don't know what it is you can always google it. For instance if you use Verizon DSL, you can search for Verizon DSL SMTP settings.